# Concatenate a string with an int in C

Tags: c, string, int, strcat

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void)
{
    //declaring variables
    int num[10], action;
    char longText[80], shortText[80] = { 0 };

    //Program's Main menu
    printf("You can use the following options:\nPlease select your desired action.\n");
    scanf("%d", &action);
    switch (action) //All of the possible options for the user
    {
        case 1:
        {
            switchIf(num);
            break;
        }
        case 2:
        {
            newNumbers(num);
            break;
        }
        case 3: 
        {
            longToShortText(longText, shortText);
            break;
        }
    }
}
void longToShortText(char longText[], char shortText[])
{
    int i, j = 0, counter = 1, size;
    printf("Please enter a series of letters.\n");
    scanf("%s", longText);
    size = strlen(longText);
    for (i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
    if (longText[i] == longText[i + 1])
        ++counter;
    else
    {
        shortText[j] = longText[i];
        strcat(shortText[j], counter); // i know this is wrong, but i couldn't make it work with another string either.
        printf("%c", shortText[j]);
        counter = 1;
        ++j;
    }
}
```

}
That's a piece of my code, the function is getting a group of chars (ie : aaabbbccc) and it suppose to count how many times every char is being entered, then it sends the letter to another string, and then i want to concatenate counter's value into shortText[j], and then the program crashes. (error given in erorr list is "'strcat': different types for formal and actual parameter 1/2"
What would be the way to make it work?

Comment: "it does not work" or the like is never a good enough problem description, please be more specific. what does happen, what does work, what is supposed to happen instead, give error message if there is any, and reduce the code to the minimum to reproduce the problem.

Comment: `sprintf(target_str, "%s%d", string_part, counter)`, but it's better for you to use `snprintf` to avoid overflow. And please: `longToShortText(char longText[], char shortText[])`. The char arrays decay into pointers, the function has no way of knowing how big the arrays are, change it to `longToShortText(char* longText, char* shortText, size_t long_len, size_t short_len)` and pass the size of the arrays to the function

Comment: What do you want to have in `shortText` for `"aaabb"` do you want `"a3b2"`? Or `"a\0\0\0\3b\0\0\0\2"`? If you want the first just convert `int` into `char*` with `sprintf` and then use `strcat` for the second case you should use `memcpy`

Answer (score 0):

Two possible ways. For case `"aaabb"`:

If you want "a3b2":

```
shortText[j] = longText[i];
++j;
char aux[20];
sprintf(aux, "%d", counter);
printf("aux: %s, j: %d\n", aux, j);
strcat(shortText+j, aux);
counter = 1;
j += strlen(aux);
```

If you want "a\0\0\0\3b\0\0\0\2" (Example assumes 4 bytes int)

```
shortText[j] = longText[i];
++j;
memcpy(shortText+j, &counter, sizeof(counter));
printf("%c, %d, %d, %d\n", shortText[j-1], counter, sizeof(counter), j);
counter = 1;
j += sizeof(counter);
```

Take care in the second case as you won't be able to use string functions anymore (Like `strcat`, `strcpy`, ...)

Answer (score 0):

I tried [answering a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34060584/2006333) today.

Refer to the below code that I answered there, and check if it helps you.

The output of code is `a3b2d4`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define LONG 80
#define SHORT 20
void longtext(char longtxt[LONG], char shorttxt[SHORT])
{
    int i, j=0, count=0, tmp;
    char letter;
    for (i = 0; i <= strlen(longtxt); ++i)
    {
        if (i == 0)
        {
            letter = longtxt[i];
            ++count;
        }
        else if (letter == longtxt[i])
            ++count;
        else
        {
            shorttxt[j] = letter;
            snprintf(&shorttxt[j + 1],2,"%d",count);
            j += 2;
            count = 1;
            letter = longtxt[i];
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    char longtxt[LONG] = "aaabbdddd",shorttxt[SHORT];
    longtext(longtxt,shorttxt);
    printf("%s", shorttxt);
}
```

> **NOTE:** You may need to increase the size from 2, if count exceeds a
>   character size.

Comment: If you think you've found a duplicate question please flag it as such rather than posting duplicate answers.

Comment: @ChrisF .. Okay, answered because question was not exactly duplicate.. but final answer would be same in my opinion!